# Get objects coordinates inside a grid

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, coordinates

I have a grid that looks like this:

```
<grid name="my_grid"></grid>
```

Then I have an class object called paramBox named *myBox*. This object is inserted to the grid like this:

```
my_grid.Children.Add(myBox);
```

Now here is my question:
Is there a way to get the coordinates (x and y values) for *myBox* inside the grid?
I have tried using PointToScreen without any luck. Is it even posible to get the coordinates if I dont declare any x and y values inside the class/grid?

Comment: i'm not sure if there's an equivalent in wpf, but in winforms each control has the property Bounds, where you can get the x- and y-value

Comment: A `Grid` doesn't really have an x/y coordinate system. It uses columns/rows. If you're looking to use an x/y coordinate system then you should use `Canvas`.

Comment: OK, Maybe I have to look and see if I can change it then

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using a Canvas instead of Grid. Then If you are going to move an element you can do like this (This may not fit exactly to you problem but I may have some ideas):

On the element `MouseDown` Event:

```
private void Element _MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Point position = e.GetPosition(myCanvas);

    this.myElement.RenderTransform =
            new TranslateTransform(position.X - myElement/ 2.0,
                                    position.Y - myElement/ 2.0);

        this.myCanvas.MouseMove += myCanvas_MouseMove;

        this.myCanvas.MouseUp += myCanvas_MouseUp;
}

private void myCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point position = e.GetPosition(this.myCanvas);
    ((TranslateTransform)(this.myElement.RenderTransform)).X = position.X - myElement/ 2.0;
        //
    ((TranslateTransform)(this.myElement.RenderTransform)).Y = position.Y - myElement/ 2.0;
}

 private void myCanvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     this.myCanvas.MouseMove -= myCanvas_MouseMove;

     this.myCanvas.MouseUp -= myCanvas_MouseUp;
}
```

Comment: This does not work. I get different values but the object is not moving. I guess Mouse.GetPosition depend on where the mouse are

Comment: `Now here is my question: Is there a way to get the coordinates (x and y values) for myBox inside the grid?`
So your are going to move that object. Am I correct?

Comment: Well I am going to move an other object and I want to know when that object is over the first object. I already know where the object which is moving have for coordinates (I check the mouse position). But I can not check if it is over _myBox_ because I can not get the coordinates for _myBox_

Comment: It was hard, understanding all of these from the initial question!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Margin Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to move the control around.

> The margin is the space between this object and other objects that
>   will be adjacent when layout creates the UI. The other objects
>   participating in layout might be peer objects (such as other objects
>   in the collection of a common parent control), or might also be this
>   object's parent in the visual tree.

or use canvas instead of grid as @m-y suggested. here is a [DEMO](http://wpftutorial.net/Canvas.html)